# Difference between node access methods in Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

I'm having a little confusion around how exactly selectors in Javascript/jQuery work. I have two methods called in almost identical ways that seem to return different selectors and I can't quite tell why.

```
if (document.URL.indexOf("search?s=") !== -1){
    updateOldSearch();
} else {
    $("li a:contains('Search')").bind("click", replaceWithSearch);
}
```

Everything works fine in the else statement here:

```
function replaceWithSearch(){
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(searchWrapper, this); //Works fine
}
```

But when I access it in what seems to me to be an identical way(clearly it's not actually identical) it breaks

```
function updateOldSearch(){
    var courseTab = $("li a:contains('Search')");
    courseTab.parentNode.replaceChild(newBox, courseTab); //parentNode is undefined
}
```

Any explanations as to what is happening behind the scenes here? Is there some automatic casting that jQuery does that I'm abusing?

Comment: `$()` returns a jQuery object, not a DOM Node. Two very different things. the jQuery object does not have all the same methods that the DOM node has.

Comment: @KevinB are jQuery objects automatically cast to DOM nodes when they get passed into a callback?

Comment: That depends on the callback, but typically yes.

Comment: You will need to use a loop in your `updateOldSearch` function. You need to do something like: `$("li a:contains('Search')")[0]` to be able to access parentNode.

Comment: @KevinB fascinating! I had no idea. Pros and cons of duck-typing I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first example, `this` represents a native DOM node. In the second, `courseTab` represents a jQuery object.

Try this for the second example:

```
function updateOldSearch(){
    var courseTab = $("li a:contains('Search')").get(0);
    courseTab.parentNode.replaceChild(newBox, courseTab);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some automatic casting that jQuery does?

Kinda. Your event listener works because [jQuery calls it so that](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-handler) "*the this keyword is a reference to the element where the event is being delivered*". Notice "the element", not "the jQuery collection".

In contrast, your `courseTab` variable holds a jQuery instance (instead of a plain DOM node). Use

```
$("li a:contains('Search')").each(function() {
    this.parentNode.replaceChild(newBox, this);
});
```

or

```
$("li a:contains('Search')").replaceWith(newBox);
```